# Python remove duplicate elements from xml tree

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml structure with some elements which are not unique. So I managed to sort the subtrees and I can filter propper the elements which I have more than one time. But the remove function seems not to apply.

My XML Structure looks simplified like this:

```
<root>
  <page>
    <text>blabla blub unique</text>
    <text>blabla blub not unique</text>
    <text>blabla blub not unique</text><!-- line should be removed -->
    <text>blabla blub not unique</text><!-- line should be removed -->
    <text>blabla blub not unique</text><!-- line should be removed -->
    <text>blabla blub again unique</text>
  </page>
  <page>
    <text>2nd blabla blub unique</text>
    <text>2nd blabla blub not unique</text>
    <text>2nd blabla blub not unique</text><!-- line should be removed -->
    <text>2nd blabla blub again unique</text>
  </page>
</root>
```

I want to remove double strings on each page, so I'm iterating over pages and over elements in page in two for loops: (extract of important lines, I hope didn't forget anything)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
self.tree = ET.parse(path)
self.root = self.tree.getroot()
self.prev = None
# [...]
for page in self.root:                     # iterate over pages
    for elem in page:
        if elements_equal(elem, self.prev):
            print("found duplicate: %s" % elem.text)   # equal function works well
            page.remove(elem) # <---- removes just one line
            continue
        self.prev = elem
# [...]
self.tree.write("out.xml") # 2 duplicate lines still there....
```

**update:** The code seems to work, but it removes just one duplicate, not all

Comment: Did you try root.remove(elem) instead of page?

Comment: i think it's a list ; if so, try making it a set and see if the duplicates are removed. I guess it boils down on how the __eq__ method is implemented for a node, if at all

Comment: it should be an element of xmlTree Object, but I have no glue how it is implemented. When I try to remove from root it says: `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Comment: how to make it a set? What do you mean by eq method? @omu_negru

Comment: well, just doing set(your_list) , or any iterator for that matter , should do the trick. To check if the eq method is properly implemented,  get the second and third nodes and see if second == third returns true (it should)

Comment: ok, I figured out, that the code is actually working, but just for the first dup, but if I have e.g. 4 dups, just the first is removed. I updated the question. @omu_negru

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how you've defined `elements_equal`, but (shamelessly adapted from [Testing Equivalence of xml.etree.ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905380/testing-equivalence-of-xml-etree-elementtree)) this works for me:

EDIT: store a list of each element to be removed whilst iterating over `page` and then remove them rather than doing the removal within one loop.

EDIT: Noticed a small typo in the code in the comparison of the element tags and correct it.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

path = 'in.xml'

tree = ET.parse(path)
root = tree.getroot()
prev = None

def elements_equal(e1, e2):
    if type(e1) != type(e2):
        return False
    if e1.tag != e2.tag: return False
    if e1.text != e2.text: return False
    if e1.tail != e2.tail: return False
    if e1.attrib != e2.attrib: return False
    if len(e1) != len(e2): return False
    return all([elements_equal(c1, c2) for c1, c2 in zip(e1, e2)])

for page in root:                     # iterate over pages
    elems_to_remove = []
    for elem in page:
        if elements_equal(elem, prev):
            print("found duplicate: %s" % elem.text)   # equal function works well
            elems_to_remove.append(elem)
            continue
        prev = elem
    for elem_to_remove in elems_to_remove:
        page.remove(elem_to_remove)
# [...]
tree.write("out.xml")
```

Gives:

```
$ python undupe.py
found duplicate: blabla blub not unique
found duplicate: 2nd blabla blub not unique
$ cat out.xml
<root>
  <page>
    <text>blabla blub unique</text>
    <text>blabla blub not unique</text>
    <text>blabla blub again unique</text>
  </page>
  <page>
    <text>2nd blabla blub unique</text>
    <text>2nd blabla blub not unique</text>
    <text>2nd blabla blub again unique</text>
  </page>
```

Comment: Equals function works proper, that's not the problem. But I have a similar, thanks.

Comment: @abimelex: then there is something else I don't understand about your problem. I've posted my full working code in case it helps.

Comment: haha ok, I was thinking in wrong direction... the program works and also your code with the example. The Problem comes with my example, when we have not just two unique elements. Like 4 times the same row. Both codes are somehow not deleting all duplicates... don't know why... @xnx updated my question

Comment: Ah yes - it's not working because you're (we're) removing the `text` elements within the iteration over `page`'s children. This won't work because removing the element will bring the iteration to a premature halt

Comment: oh okay... I don't get the behavior reason, but I figured out a solution... I will just edit your answer and then accept it if it's okay for you.

Comment: oh well, I see, you already did it, came up with the same solution ;)