# Check and remove duplicated children tags in XML

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I'm parsing an XML-like file via Element Tree in python and and writing the content to a pandas dataframe.

I'm currently facing the following problem: The existence of children tags will be variant for different tags. This wouldn't be a problem with the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568126/how-can-i-check-the-existence-of-attributes-and-tags-in-xml-before-parsinga). However, the complicated part is that some tags have duplicated children tags while others don't. For example first product tag has two (different) article numbers and two equal product_types (duplicate) while the second only has one of each.

```
<main>
    <product>
       <article_nr>B00024J7C6</article_nr>
       <article_nr>44253</article_nr>
       <product_type>x</product_type>
       <product_type>x</product_type>
    </product>

    <product>
       <article_nr>B00024J7C7</article_nr>
       <product_type>y</product_type>
    </product>
</main>
```

What I'd like to do is:
1.) remove the duplicates for 'product_type' and
2.) set the value NULL if there doesn't exist a second article_nr, otherwise take the value.

My code so far:

```
def create_dataframe(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('article_nr', 'article_nr2', 'product_type', 'product_type2','product_type2'))
    for i in range(len(data)):
        obj = data.getchildren()[i].getchildren()
        row = dict(itertools.izip(['article_nr', 'article_nr2', 'product_type', 'product_type2','product_type2'], 
                       [obj[0].text, obj[1].text, obj[2].text, obj[3].text, obj[4].text]))
        row_s = pd.Series(row)
        row_s.name = i
        df = df.append(row_s)
    return df
```

This works fine with the first example, but obviously not with the second, because there are no values for the second 'article_nr' and 'product_type'.

Output should be:

```
article_nr    article_nr    product_type
B00024J7C6    44253           x
B00024J7C7    NULL            y
```

Comment: Could you please add what code you have so far and the desired output? Thanks.

Comment: so why can't you do this after parsing? why do you need to do it before?

Comment: I've added the code and the desired output @alecxe

Comment: @e4c5 thanks for your hint. I've changed the title, because it's okay or even better to do this after parsing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Python remove duplicate elements from xml tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549653/python-remove-duplicate-elements-from-xml-tree) ,maybe it can help you.
Some Thing like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
path = 'in.xml'
tree = ET.parse(path)
root = tree.getroot()
prev = None

def elements_equal(e1, e2):
    if type(e1) != type(e2):
        return False
    if e1.tag != e1.tag: return False
    if e1.text != e2.text: return False
    if e1.tail != e2.tail: return False
    if e1.attrib != e2.attrib: return False
    if len(e1) != len(e2): return False
    return all([elements_equal(c1, c2) for c1, c2 in zip(e1, e2)])

for page in root:                     # iterate over pages
    elems_to_remove = []
    for elem in page:
        if elements_equal(elem, prev):
            print("found duplicate: %s" % elem.text)   # equal function works well
            elems_to_remove.append(elem)
            continue
        prev = elem
    for elem_to_remove in elems_to_remove:
        page.remove(elem_to_remove)
tree.write("out.xml")
```

Comment: The code solved the first issue by removing all the duplicates. I solved the second one by myself with the following code:

`for product in root.findall('product'):
    article_nr = product.findall('article_nr')
    if len(article_nr) == 1:
        product.insert(1, ET.Element('article_nr'))`