# Compare two XML Elements without marshalling them

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, equality

I need to create enums in XSD. I have much enum definition, and I want to avoid duplicates, or `xjc` will stop me.

The first brutal solution was to name them differently. Now I would compare them and check if they are identical.

Unluckily:

```py
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement

xsd_prefix = "xs:"

schema = Element(xsd_prefix + "schema")

enumeration = SubElement(schema, xsd_prefix + "simpleType")
enumeration.set("name", "a")

restriction = SubElement(enumeration, xsd_prefix + "restriction")
restriction.set("base", xsd_prefix + "string")

enum1 = SubElement(restriction, xsd_prefix + "enumeration")
enum1.set("value", "a")
enum2 = SubElement(restriction, xsd_prefix + "enumeration")
enum2.set("value", "b")

enumeration2 = SubElement(schema, xsd_prefix + "simpleType")
enumeration2.set("name", "a")
restriction2 = SubElement(enumeration2, xsd_prefix + "restriction")
restriction2.set("base", xsd_prefix + "string")
enum3 = SubElement(restriction2, xsd_prefix + "enumeration")
enum3.set("value", "a")
enum4 = SubElement(restriction2, xsd_prefix + "enumeration")
enum4.set("value", "b")

enumeration2 == enumeration
```

give me `False`. If I want to compare them, I have to marshall the Element as string:

```py
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as Et
>>> Et.tostring(enumeration2, "utf-8") == Et.tostring(enumeration, "utf-8")
True
```

Is there not a smarter way to do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905380/testing-equivalence-of-xml-etree-elementtree

Comment: @balderman Thank you, but they seems not to me smarter solutions.

Comment: XML elements don't implement specific equality rules, so they are only going to test equal if they are the same Python object.

Comment: Your demo actually created two elements that are not equal, because you left out the `xsd_prefix` for the second restriction element: `restriction2.set("base", "string")`.

Comment: With that difference, your claim that the two enumerations produce the same string is also not correct, so I assume that that was an error in posting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, it's a edit mistake. Anyway, I'm searching for an alternate smarter solution. I know that equality does not work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: please, this is not a duplicate. I know how to compare them, I asking for a smarter method. Furthermore, the linked answers are not so smart...

Comment: Not liking the solutions doesn't make this not a duplicate, sorry. There are no better solutions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197570/discussion-between-marco-sulla-and-martijn-pieters).